# get number of selected row AJAX - ZEND

Tags: ajax, row, selected

actually i have the follow code working, but it is tacking alway the first record [0]: echo $this->bills[0]['id'];, how could i change it to get the record selected with double click?

Here code for the view object in zend:

```
echo '<table id="tabla_listado_cuentas">';
  echo '<thead>';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo "<th><a href=''>Id Factura</a></th>";
  echo "<th><a href=''>Estado Factura</a></th>";
  echo '</tr>';
  echo '</thead>';
  echo '<tbody>';
  echo '<td id="ident">'.$bill['id'].'</td>';
  echo '<td id="td_con_separacion" class="estado">'.$bill['estado']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo '</tbody>';
  echo '</table>';
  echo '</form>';
  ?>
  <script>
     $(".estado").editable("<?php echo $this->baseUrl().'/bills/update-Ajax'?>", {
     indicator : "Guardando...",
     tooltip   : 'Click para editar',
     data   : "  {'payed':'Pagada','acepted':'Aceptada','pending':'Pendiente','denied':'Deniegada'}",
      type: 'select',
      submit: 'Ok',
      event : "dblclick",
      placeholder : '...',
      submitdata : function(value, settings) {
         return {column: "estado", estado: "<?php echo $this->bills[0]['estado']; ?>", bill: "<?php echo $this->bills[0]['id'];?>"};
          }
});
</script>
```

Thanks a lot in advance